# Auto login into laravel webapp from another web app that is sharing same database

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Our project currently is build upon Yii but we're considering moving to laravel. However since our project got a huge number of modules to migrate, we're playing around the idea of running both Yii and Laravel webapps concurrently so we can migrate the modules over time (instead of all at once) to Laravel.

Both of our Yii and Laravel will be sharing the same database, hence the same user table. Is it possible to do a login (to Laravel) after our user login from our Yii login page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to, provided you have an identical setup and subdomains between the two. This would allow you to share cookies. What are you using for the session driver?

Alternatively you could setup a shared api that handles authentication  for both, though that may be more involved than you'd want.

Comment: I see some problems regarding password-hashing. I think Laravel uses different keys to hash and compare passwords during registration/login process. So when a user logs in via Laravel the password won't match the hash Yii created during registration and vice versa.

Comment: That was my thoughts too and why I mentioned the shared auth api. I'm not familiar with yii so can't really comment on how it would all jive together.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create custom auth provider:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/replacing-the-laravel-authentication-with-a-custom-authentication

Migrate Yii members to Laravel table, make passwords empty. Add condition to your CustomAuthProvider that such user can't be authenticated.

If anyone tries to login to Laravel without having a password, redirect to Yii login with a message explaining why he landed here.

On Yii login (successful ;)) update Laravel password with Laravel api:
`Hash::make($request->newPassword)`

If in Yii you had hidden redirect to Laravel frontend (could be session variable) than after last step try authenticating with provided data to Laravel.

This should explain the workflow you need to implement.